# Download of an email attatchment on Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, triggers, jenkins-plugins, attachment

I have been testing the Jenkins "**Poll Mail Trigger**" plugin to trigger a project via email. To develop the project I need to download the attached file that is sent.

In the project settings, I enable the only download option that exists: **"*Download to a timestamped Directory*".**

Also, the only information regarding the download is this: **"The *Attachments* field, allows you to determine what to do with email attachments. If attachments are downloaded, the `pmt_attachmentsDirectory` variable with be set to the download directory."**

Then, after doing several tests without configuring any directory for the download of the attached file -assuming that the download should have been automatic-, I proceeded to change the environment variables in the Jenkins configuration, I put the following:

- **Name:** *pmt_attachmentsDirectory*
- **Value:** *D: *

So, what I'm trying to do is save the file to my Drive D: \

The file is never downloaded to the specified disk, and just for verification, I am trying to move the file with the following Windows command:

```
move "% pmt_attachmentsDirectory%" "D: \ Users \ wrodriguez \ Downloads \ Test_Programs"
```

And finally it throws me the following output: ***"The system cannot find the specified file."***

So, I am really lost here, can anybody help me with this issue? Is there another plugin on Jenkins that I can use to download an attatchment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked on that plugin (or Jenkins) in 5 years, so forgive my rustiness.

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pollmailboxtrigger/PollMailboxTrigger.java#L303-L305), the plugin creates a timestamped folder, and saves any attachments there.

It then injects an environment variable named `pmt_attachmentsDirectory` into the Jenkins job instance's environment variables - the value is the absolute path of folder (it's not configurable).

**Troubleshooting:**

- have you [enabled saving Attachments](https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin/raw/master/src/main/site/images/screenshot-version-1.022.png) in the Plugin options?
- check the job instance's environment variables - does it have `pmt_attachmentsDirectory` listed?

  - print the value of `pmt_attachmentsDirectory` - e.g. `echo "%pmt_attachmentsDirectory%"` - what does it say?
  - does the directory exist?
  - does the directory contain any files?
- does the "View Polling Log" have any errors?
- do the Jenkins logs have any errors?

**Other notes:**

- `"% pmt_attachmentsDirectory%"` - shouldn't have a space e.g. should be `"%pmt_attachmentsDirectory%"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you were really helpful, I will see how to configurate the other PC to track the file.

Comment: Sorry @wrodriguez - that's the extent of my knowledge. And I'm not available to personally troubleshoot this issue. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, @nickgrealy I have a question. Is there a way I can stablish the root where the attachment will be downloaded? Thanks for your time

Comment: No, from the code it looks like it just creates a random tmp directory... https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin/blob/e8b93fe5a26d75c9d2eb89e3e66de12bb7dd5406/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pollmailboxtrigger/mail/utils/MailWrapperUtils.java#L165